# Should a knowledge graph be a valid ontology?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs, knowledge-graph

I wonder if an RDF document that resembles a knowledge graph should also be a valid OWL document [ready for reasoning]? In other words, is it okay if we have a valid RDF document but not being able to perform reasoning on it and only perform SPARQL queries?

Comment: sure, why not? You can have RDF data even without a schema, for SPARQL this is sufficient. Clearly, without a more complex schema, you'll miss any of its benefits - but sure, why not?

Comment: Thanks, I asked because I am currently making a knowledge graph by looking at the classes and object properties in an ontology. This means any individual in my knowledge graph has rdf:type and any relation can be mapped to a property in the ontology. BUT in this way, I do not care about the axioms and assertions regarding the classes in ontology. I only use the classes and properties. Is it good practice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be a valid RDF document. OWL ontologies and RDF documents overlap but do not coincide. There's no requirement for that.